# Creating a Gearman Worker in C

Tags: c, api, gearman

I've been trying to implement a Gearman worker with their C API (libgearman). But their documentation for the C API is poor and not complete. Although its very similar to creating workers in other languages such as PHP, I am still unable to Register a function in the worker via *gearman_worker_add_function();*

To be specific, I am unable to find out how to create an object of *gearman_worker_fn* .

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this documentation](http://gearman.org/docs/api/group__gearman__constants.html#g733a2edcf3ccf3b70c4ac3174656dfa5):

> typedef void*( gearman_worker_fn)(gearman_job_st *job, void *context,
>   size_t *result_size, gearman_return_t *ret_ptr)
>
> Definition at line 407 of file constants.h.

This is a function pointer typedef: Basically you just need to create a function with the correct signature (returns `void *`, takes in `gearman_job_st *`, `void *`, `size_t *`, `gearman_return_t *`), and then pass in the function name.

Example:

```
void *do_work(gearman_job_st *job, void *context, size_t *result_size, gearman_return_t *ret_ptr)
{
    do_something();
}

/* Later... */

    gearman_worker_add_function(worker, function_name, timeout, do_work, context);
```

Notice that I just pass the function name-- this degrades to a "function pointer".

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Thanks !

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the tick, but feel free to vote me up as well if the answer proves helpful ;-)